# Grouping Data under Headers

Tags: php, html

Hi guys i currently have a address book that displays the information like this:

```
Extension Name  Department  Email   Cellphone
   1         jurgen   home       1@       1
   2         dawn     work       2@       2    
   3         mike     away       3@       33
```

Is there a way to display the information by Department? such as this: Where it shows the users under each department that they fall under, basically grouping them? be gentle :) im new to coding :D

```
Extension Name  Email                    Cellphone          
ALPINE DEALER PRINCIPAL     
7813    Garth   123@alpinemotors.co.za       2
7898    Sam     3653@alpinemotors.co.za      4

AFTER-SALES DIRECTOR            
7709    Bruce   6342@alpinemotors.co.za      3
```

Heres my code for the view.php page (on a side note i made a search bar but dont know how to code it to search the names field actively, so as they type in the search bar, the tables filter without having to press enter)

```
default:
$sql ="SELECT * FROM address ORDER BY name ASC";
$data = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<h2>Alpine VW Extension List</h2>
<table class="tableStyleClass">
<tr>
<th width="100">Extension</th>
<th width="100">Name</th>
<th width="200">Department</th>
<th width="200">Email</th>
<th width="200">Cellphone</th>
<th width="200" colspan="2">Admin</th>
</tr>
<td colspan="5" align="right"><?php if($disable!=1){?><div align="right <a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?mode=add"?mode=add>Add Contact</a><?php }else{?>Contact Book is Full<?php } ?></div></td>
<?php
$rowColor = 0;
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )){
if($rowColor==0){
?>
<tr class="oddClassStyle">
<?php 
$rowColor =1;
}elseif($rowColor==1){
?>
<tr class="evenClassStyle">
<?php
$rowColor = 0;
}
?>
<td><?=$info['Ext'];?></td>
<td><?=$info['name'];?></td>
<td><?=$info['department'];?></td>
<td><a href=mailto:"<?=$info['email'];?>"><?=$info['email'];?></a></td>
<td><?=$info['phone'];?></td>
<td><a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?id=<?=$info['id'];?>&name=<?=$info['name'];?>&phone=<?=$info['phone'];?>&email=<?=$info['email']; >&mode=edit" >Edit </a></td>
<td><a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?id=<?=$info['id']; >&mode=remove">Remove</a></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
<?php
break;
```

(THE ABOVE CODE WAS FIXED FROM ANSWERS BELOW)

Ok now that i have that sorted my edit button doesnt seem to work. it supposed to display the current info and then once edited, you click the edit button and it changes the information for that user.

Here is the code i was using previously:

```
case 'edit':
?>
<h2>Editing: <?=$_GET['name'];?></h2>
<form name="form1" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?mode=edited" method="post">
<table width="399" class="tableStyleClassTwo">
<tr><td width="87">Name:</td>
<td width="551"><div align="left">
<input type="text" value="<?=$_GET['name'];?>" name="name" />
</div></td></tr>
<tr><td>Phone:</td><td><div align="left">
<input type="text" value="<?=$_GET['phone'];?>" name="phone" />
</div></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email:</td><td><div align="left">
<input type="text" value="<?=$_GET['email'];?>" name="email" />
</div></td></tr>
<tr><td>Extension:</td><td><div align="left">
<input type="text" value="<?=$_GET['Ext'];?>" name="Ext" />
</div></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">Back</a> |<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Save Changes" /></td></tr>
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="edited">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$_GET['id'];?>">
</table>
</form>
<?php 
break;

case 'edited':
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$department = $_POST['department'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$Ext = $_POST ['Ext'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "UPDATE address SET name = '" . $name ."', phone = '" . $phone . "', email = '" . $email . "', Ext = '" . $Ext . "' WHERE id = '" . $id . "'";
mysql_query($sql);
header('location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query -

```
    $sql = "SELECT t1.Ext, t1.name, t1.email, t1.cellphone FROM address t1 join address t2 on t1.id=t2.id ORDER BY t2.department";
```

EDIT:

```
    <?php
$sql = "SELECT t1.Ext, t1.name, t1.email, t1.cellphone FROM address t1 join address t2 on t1.id=t2.id ORDER BY t2.department";
$data = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<h2>Alpine VW Extension List</h2>
<table class="tableStyleClass">
<tr>
<th width="100">Extension</th>
<th width="100">Name</th>
<th width="200">Email</th>
<th width="200">Cellphone</th>
<th width="200" colspan="2">Admin</th>
</tr>
<td colspan="5" align="right"><?php if($disable!=1){?><div align="right <a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?mode=add"?mode=add>Add Contact</a><?php }else{?>Contact Book is Full<?php } ?></div></td>
<?php
$rowColor = 0;
$deptName = "";
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )){ 
  if($deptName === "" || $deptName != $info['department']) {
      $deptName = $info['department'];
      echo "<tr> <th colspan=6> $deptName </td> </th> </tr>\n";
  }  

if($rowColor==0){
?>
<tr class="oddClassStyle">
<?php 
$rowColor =1;
}elseif($rowColor==1){
?>
<tr class="evenClassStyle">
<?php
$rowColor = 0;
}
?>
<td><?=$info['Ext'];?></td>
<td><?=$info['name'];?></td>
<td><a href=mailto:"<?=$info['email'];?>"><?=$info['email'];?></a></td>
<td><?=$info['phone'];?></td>
<td><a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?id=<?=$info['id'];?>&name=<?=$info['name'];?>&phone=<?=$info['phone'];?>&email=<?=$info['email']; >&mode=edit" >Edit </a></td>
<td><a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?id=<?=$info['id']; >&mode=remove">Remove</a></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
<?php
break;
?>
```

Comment: under where would i put this if i may ask :)

Comment: edited @Unknown Coder... Change the query itself.  And put the department name in a row like header.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
$depts = [];
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM address ORDER BY department, name");

// build the appropriate data structure that organizes contacts into different departments
// by looping through each contact, check if department exist (if not create the department) and add contact to the department
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    if (!isset($depts[$row['department']])) {
        $depts[$row['department']] = [];
    }
    $depts[$row['department']][] = $row;
}
?>

<h2>Alpine VW Extension List</h2>
<table class="tableStyleClass">
    <tr>
        <th width="100">Extension</th>
        <th width="100">Name</th>
        <th width="200">Email</th>
        <th width="200">Cellphone</th>
        <th width="200" colspan="2">Admin</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">
        <?php if ($disable != 1) : ?>
            <a href="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?mode=add">Add Contact</a>
        <?php else : ?>
            <span>Contact Book is Full</span>
        <?php endif ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($depts as $dname => $contacts) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6"><?= $dname ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($contacts as $contact) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $contact['ext'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $contact['name'] ?></td>
                <td><a href="mailto:"<?= $contact['email'] ?>"><?= $contact['email'] ?></a></td>
                <td><?= $contact['phone'] ?></td>
                <td><a href="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?id=<?= $contact['id'] ?>&mode=edit" >Edit </a></td>
                <td><a href="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?id=<?= $contact['id'] ?>&mode=remove">Remove</a></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

On another note, stop using [mysql_*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) functions. There's a big red warning that says it is **deprecated** for good reasons. Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or better [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead!

And make better use of CSS (and use less attributes such as `align="right"`). You can use [:nth-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) selector (particularly with `:even` and `:odd`)to do your alternating styles for your table.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfectly! Just 1 questions if i may. where would i add the <b> to make the headers bold and maybe increase the font size. and also my edit button doesnt seem to be working. Would you mind letting me know if you can see anything wrong with it? I have updated the question above with the edit button code. Once again thank you so much!

Comment: Use CSS to style your `th` tags with [font-weight](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp) and [font-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp). 

Instead of passing all your values in your edit link's `href`, pass only the `id` and the `mode`. In your `edit` switch case, query the record with the ID such as `$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM address WHERE id = {$_POST['id']}");`